# Semiconductor Quantum Dots

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, quantum-dots

Can someone recommend some good books on semiconductor quantum dots(InGaAs, GaAs etc..) from the perspective of a beginner student. I mostly want to learn about the optical states (the photoluminescence) and the optical detection of nuclear magnetic resonance of the nuclei in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following books are helpful for your studies,

1. Semiconductor quantum dots by L. Banyai, Stephan W. Koch
2. Phys Props of III-V Semicond Cpds - InP, InAs, GaAs, GaP, InGaAs, InGaAsP by S. Adachi
3. Single Semiconductor Quantum Dots by Peter Michler
4. Semiconductor Nanocrystal Quantum Dots by Claus Klingshirn
5. Optical Characterization of Semiconductors. Infrared, Raman, and Photoluminescence 
   Spectroscopy by Sidney Perkowitz
6. Complete Introduction to Nuclear Magnetic Resonance and NMR Spectroscopy by Roger S. 
   Macomber
7. Nuclear magnetic resonance: volume 45 by Sharon E. Ashbrook, Vasudevan Ramesh

Please download and read these books.